# Is there a way to assert download file with partial filename in testcafe?

Tags: javascript, download, filenames, assert, testcafe

I am working on testcafe UI test automation and I have a download link which downloads a file from server but filename is created on the server with server time including seconds. I want to check if the file exists like shown in the testcafe example [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/blob/master/examples/wait-for-file-download/test.js)

I was trying to use [logger](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests.html#log-http-requests) to read the file name from response header and find it that way but problem is that UI is calling an API which is a different url so logger is not able to intercept the request/response either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [globby](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globby) module to use [globs](https://github.com/mrmlnc/fast-glob#pattern-syntax) (filename patterns) when waiting for a file.

Add the following functions to your test:

```js
const globby = require('globby');

function existsSync (glob) {
   return globby.sync(glob).length;
}

function unlinkSync (glob) {
   for(const file of globby.sync(glob))
      fs.unlinkSync(file);
}
```

and then use `existsSync` and `unlinkSync`instead of `fs.existsSync` and `fs.unlinkSync` in your test.

Comment: You can inspect how to test file download in TestCafe using [this](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/check-downloaded-file-name-and-content) runnable example.